# How to scale the number of Ingress pods

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to scale the number of Ingress pods based on load? I currently have:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-service
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```

and the Ingress Controller with the appropriate `nginx-ingress-controller`.

I had previously though that the ingress-controller will handle scaling for us? But what is the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Ingress can not be scaled, ingress is a set of traffic routing rules and configuration.

Ingress Controller on the other hand can.

The "dummy" way to scale nginx-ingress with the number of nodes in cluster would be to run it as a DaemonSet.

A more sophisticated aproach to this, would be to use [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) which can scale based on resource utilisation.

In both cases you do not scale the Ingress, but the Ingress Controller, meaning this is not related to traffic/load for that one ingress, but for all ingresses (of given type if you have different)

Comment: Thanks! this makes total sense!!